# Have to redirect to page after login succsess; Its now just reload (refresh) page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using  login.js

```
var x = 10;
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#do-login').click(function(){
              var login = $('#login');
              var pass = $('#password');
              var obj = $(this);
              if ( login.val().length === 0 ) {
                     obj.next('span')
                     .attr('class', 'inline-help')
                     .html('Empty <b>Login</b>').hide().fadeIn('slow');
                     login.focus();
                     return false;
              } else if ( pass.val().length === 0 ) {
                     obj.next('span')
                     .attr('class', 'inline-help')
                     .html('Empty <b>Password</b>').fadeIn('slow');
                     pass.focus();
                     return false;
              }

              $.ajax({
                     url : 'login-check.php' ,
                     type : 'POST',
                     data : {
                            'login' : login.val(),
                            'password' : pass.val(),
                            isAjax : true
                     },
                     dataType : 'json' ,
                     success : function(data){
                if(data === false)
                {
                    alert('You have reached maximum login limit, Please try login after 15 minutes.');
                }
                else if ( data === true )
                {
                    obj.next('span')
                    .attr('class', 'inline-info')
                    .html('Logged In <b>Successfully</b> !')
                    .hide().fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $('#login-form').slideUp('fast',function()
                        {
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                                            location.reload(true);
                            },1000);
                        });
                    },1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.next('span')
                    .attr('class', 'inline-help')
                    .html('Invalid <b>Login/Password</b><li style=padding-left:220px;>(Attempts <b>' + data + '/10</b>)').hide().fadeIn();
                }
                     }
              });
              return false;
       });
});
```

I have to redirect after login success to `http://myurl.com/panel`. I have changed as my knowledge but I didn't get any success. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, setting the location.href value.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/window/location

```
var x = 10;
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#do-login').click(function(){
              var login = $('#login');
              var pass = $('#password');
              var obj = $(this);
              if ( login.val().length === 0 ) {
                     obj.next('span')
                     .attr('class', 'inline-help')
                     .html('Empty <b>Login</b>').hide().fadeIn('slow');
                     login.focus();
                     return false;
              } else if ( pass.val().length === 0 ) {
                     obj.next('span')
                     .attr('class', 'inline-help')
                     .html('Empty <b>Password</b>').fadeIn('slow');
                     pass.focus();
                     return false;
              }

              $.ajax({
                     url : 'login-check.php' ,
                     type : 'POST',
                     data : {
                            'login' : login.val(),
                            'password' : pass.val(),
                            isAjax : true
                     },
                     dataType : 'json' ,
                     success : function(data){
                if(data === false)
                {
                    alert('You have reached maximum login limit, Please try login after 15 minutes.');
                }
                else if ( data === true )
                {
                    obj.next('span')
                    .attr('class', 'inline-info')
                    .html('Logged In <b>Successfully</b> !')
                    .hide().fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $('#login-form').slideUp('fast',function()
                        {
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                 location.href = 'http://myurl.com/panel';
                            },1000);
                        });
                    },1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.next('span')
                    .attr('class', 'inline-help')
                    .html('Invalid <b>Login/Password</b><li style=padding-left:220px;>(Attempts <b>' + data + '/10</b>)').hide().fadeIn();
                }
                     }
              });
              return false;
       });
});
```

Comment: Thaks Bro This Is Worked For Me

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Grosgojat is right about the href, however unless you're using cookies, if you declare the success page here anyone peeking at the js in the browser console will be able get the address, no? Can only suggest storing the desired address in an ajax json success response and passing that to the location.href via private variable.

Plus:
this would still be very low level security. The destination page exists on the web so can always be approached directly, thus bypassing the login games. In principle you should be using cookies and/or Oauth 2.0 security with https transport... and suddenly my eyes are receding and mouth is drying up. Good luck!

Comment: The http://myurl.com/panel page have to be protected by Session or Cookie. You should always put security code on a server side language, not in Client side Javascript, because it could be modified by any user. 

In that case, I hope a session is set in login-check.php if login is correct. Each page wich require a login protection have to verify session before rendering HTML and perform an http 301 redirection if session isn't set.